# I lose posted data after some time with heroku postgresql

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a nodejs app hosted free on heroku.My create and get route's are working.If i register new user and then get the whole list of user's i get the newly registered user.But after some time he is gone.What is happening?

I did not maked re-reployment of my app.

I am using knexjs as sql builder,and it is working fine with local db.

Code example from post request
I am getting success true,but when i go into resources in the heroku postgresql
i see no extra number inserted - i still see 6/10 000 rows in table,
that 6 are the initialy ones from the deployment just to seed example data.

```
async function postCustomer(user){
    const existing = await db.select('*').from('customer').where('email', user.email).reduce(helpers.getFirst);
    if (!existing) {
        const password = user.password ? await helpers.createBcryptHash(user.password): '';
        const newUser = {
          id: helpers.generateUuid(),
          email: user.email,
          first_name:user.first_name,
          password
        };
        await db.insert(newUser).into('customer');
        return { success: true, user: getCleanUserAndJwt(newUser), registered: true };
    } else {
      return { success: false, message: "User already exists." };
    }
}
```

// The proc file

```
web: knex migrate:rollback && knex migrate:latest && knex seed:run && node server.js
```

Comment: Without sharing any of your code it will be difficult to help.  Can you share the file(s) related to saving the user?

Comment: Are you storing the users in an in-memory JavaScript Object? If so, the application sleeps after 30 minutes, and all your in-memory stuff will not be remembered.

Comment: You are right,i edited my question.Please help me